rasterio fillnodata documentation confusion, only fill masked holes
I am trying to fill nodata (3,4e38) pixels in a raster only there where the pixels in a mask are 1. If the pixels in the mask are 0 the nodata should not be filled. When filling the nodata the valid values of the raster should be used.
To complicate things, valid data and the mask to interpolate might not touch. Nevertheless, I want rasterio to use the nearest valid value to determine what to fill the nodata with, even if that means "crossing" other nodata that's not within the mask.
If I run
fillnodata(raster, mask=mask)

I correctly only fill nodata where the mask is 1. However, the data it interpolates to is the high nodata 3,4e38 and not the valid data from the raster. This suggests to me that nodata is not correctly interpreted.
How do I correctly only fill these raster nodata values where a mask is 1, using valid data from said raster and not the mask?

You misunderstand the mask. 0 = pixels to fill, not the other way around.
What you want to do isn't possible with rasterio.fill.fillnodata.  The way the mask works is that 0 values identify pixels to fill and non-zeros identify pixel values to use the values from. There's no way to specify pixels to not fill and not use values from.
One workaround would be to fill all NoData, and then set those areas that you didn't want filled back to NoData.
Alternatively, internally, rasterio calls the GDAL C++ function GDALFillNodata which supports a NODATA=value option in addition to the mask:

papszOptions -- additional name=value options in a string list.
...
NODATA=value (starting with GDAL 2.4). Source pixels at that value
will be ignored by the interpolator. Warning: currently this will not
be honored by smoothing passes.

Unfortunately rasterio.fill.fillnodata does not allow you to pass this option in.
However, the GDAL python function osgeo.gdal.FillNodata will pass options through so you could try that instead, e.g:
gdal.FillNodata(dsBand, maskBand, options={"NODATA":3.4e38})

NOTE: for this to work, your mask band must have 1 for the nodata areas that you DON'T want to be filled, 1 for valid areas, and 0 for nodata areas that you DO want filled.
For example, I have a DEM with lakes and ocean as NoData (-9999). I want to fill the lakes NoData with values interpolated from the surrounding DEM land values. I don't want the ocean NoData filled, nor do I want the ocean NoData value used to interpolate the lakes.
So I create a mask with land and ocean == 1 and lakes = 0 and run
gdal.FillNodata(demBand, maskBand, options={"NODATA":-9999})




